# crossover() function using displaced series

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to the Pine language and I'm having trouble articulating what I want to do such that my search results are more relevant.

I want to use ta.crossunder() to compare two series however, both of the series I want to use are actually series plotted with varying offset in the x-axis and the offsets must be accounted for.

The following is taken from the default Ichimoku Cloud Indicator:

```
displacement = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Displacement")
plot(close, offset = -displacement + 1, color=#43A047, title="Lagging Span")
plot(leadLine1, offset = displacement - 1, color=#A5D6A7, title="Leading Span A")
```

I want to determine if the "lagging span" ( which is the 'close' series plotted with an offset = -displacement +1) is under the "leadLine1" (which is plotted with an offset = displacement -1) while taking the displacements into consideration.

I'm wondering if there is a quick and dirty way to compare these two series with displacements or if I will have to figure out how to rebuild each series before passing to the ta.crossunder() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative to the laggingSpan, the leadLine is plotted 2*displacement to the right. So we define a boolean series that says:

```
laggingSpan_under_leadLine1 = laggingSpan < leadLine1[2*displacement]
```